# C# - Static events on non-static classes

Tags: c#, events

There are situations where I'm quite fond of static events, but the fact that I rarely see them in other people's code makes me wonder if I'm missing something important. I found a lot of discussions about static events on this site, but most of them deal with situations that I'm not interested in (like on static classes) or where I wouldn't think of using them in the first place.

What I **am** interested in are situations where I might have many instances of something and a single instance of a long-living "manager" object that reacts to something on those instances. A very simple example to illustrate what I mean:

```
public class God {

    //the list of followers is really big and changes all the time, 
    //it seems like a waste of time to
    //register/unregister events for each and every one...  
    readonly List<Believer> Believers = new List<Believer>();

    God() {
        //...so instead let's have a static event and listen to that
        Believer.Prayed += this.Believer_Prayed;
    }

    void Believer_Prayed(Believer believer, string prayer) {
        //whatever
    }
}

public class Believer {

    public static event Action<Believer, string> Prayed;

    void Pray() {
        if (Prayed != null) {
            Prayed(this, "can i have stuff, please");
        }
    }
}
```

To me, this looks like a much cleaner and simpler solution than having an instance event and I don't have to monitor changes in the believers collection either. In cases where the Believer class can "see" the God-type class, I might sometimes use a NotifyGodOfPrayer()-method instead (which was the preferred answer in a few similar questions), but often the Believer-type class is in a "Models"-assembly where I can't or don't want to access the God class directly.

Are there any actual downsides to this approach?

Edit: Thanks to everyone who has already taken the time to answer.
My example may be bad, so I would like to clarify my question:

If I use this kind of static events in situations, where

- I'm sure there will only ever be one instance of the subscriber-object
- that is guaranteed to exist as long as the application is running
- and the number of instances I'm watching is huge

then are there potential problems with this approach that I'm not aware of?

Unless the answer to that question is "yes", I'm not really looking for alternative implementations, though I really appreciate everyone trying to be helpful.
I'm not looking for the most pretty solution (I'd have to give that prize to my own version simply for being short and easy to read and maintain :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do static events compare to non-static events in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045595/how-do-static-events-compare-to-non-static-events-in-c)

Comment: Possibly, but none of the answers are useful for my scenario.
Answer 1 (accepted): "no sending instance for static event" - not the case here
Answer 2: Unsubscribing problematic - not the case here
Answer 3: Static methods/classes - not interested in that
Answer 4: 3 use cases for static events - none of them are my use case
Answer 5: "static events are like totally terrible" - yeah, ok.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One important thing to know about events is that they cause objects which are hooked to an event not to be garbage collected until event owner is garbage collected, or until event handler is unhooked.

To put it into your example, if you had a polytheistic pantheon with many gods, where you promoted and demoted gods such as

```
new God("Svarog");
new God("Svantevit");
new God("Perun");
```

gods would remain in your RAM while they are attached to `Believer.Prayed`. This would cause your application to leak gods.

---

I'll comment on design decision also, but I understand that example you made is maybe not best copy of your real scenario.

It seems more reasonable to me not to create dependency from `God` to `Believer`, and to use events. Good approach would be to create an event aggregator which would stand between believers and gods. For example:

```
public interface IPrayerAggregator
{
    void Pray(Believer believer, string prayer);
    void RegisterGod(God god);
}

// god does
prayerAggregator.RegisterGod(this);
// believer does
prayerAggregator.Pray(this, "For the victory!");
```

Upon `Pray` method being called, event aggregator calls appropriate method of `God` class in turn. To manage references and avoid memory leaks, you could create `UnregisterGod` method or hold gods in collection of [weak references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) such as

```
public class Priest : IPrayerAggregator
{
    private List<WeakReference> _gods;

    public void Pray(Believer believer, string prayer)
    {
        foreach (WeakReference godRef in _gods) {
            God god = godRef.Target as God;
            if (god != null)
                god.SomeonePrayed(believer, prayer);
            else
                _gods.Remove(godRef);
        }
    }

    public void RegisterGod(God god)
    {
        _gods.Add(new WeakReference(god, false));
    }
}
```

---

Quick tip: Temporarily store event delegate as listeners might unhook their event handlers

```
void Pray() {
    var handler = Prayed;
    if (handler != null) {
        handler(this, "can i have stuff, please");
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Having in mind details you added about your scenario (huge number of event invokers, constant and single event watcher) I think you chose right scenario, purely for efficiency reasons. It creates least memory and cpu overhead. I wouldn't take this approach generally, but for scenario you described static event is very pragmatic solution that I might take.

One downside I see is flow of control. If your event listener is created in single instance as you say, then I would leverage singleton (anti)pattern and invoke method of `God` from `Believer` directly.

```
God.Instance.Pray(this, "For the victory!");
//or
godInstance.Pray(this, "For the victory!");
```

Why? Because then you get more granular control over performing action of praying. If you decide down the line that you need to subclass `Believer` to a special kind that doesn't pray on certain days, then you would have control over this.

Comment: I like your god names :)
In my actual application "God" would be something like "AutoSaveService", things where I'm sure there is only exactly one instance during application lifetime so multiple instances or unregistering the static event are not a concern. I like the aggregator-example, I might actually not be using this kind of approach often enough. 
Usually I do store the handler (and have a dedicated "OnPrayed"-method), I just edited it out to keep the example shorter.

Comment: Thanks :) Anyhow, aggregator example is maybe a bit too verbose. A generic aggregator could be useful. One that could take notifications of different events, and notify different listeners. [I like how Caliburn.Micro handles this](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator). Other than possible memory leak if not used properly, I don't see a problem with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think that `having an instance even` would be cleaner and defiantly more readable.
It is much more simple to view it as, an instance is preying, so **his**  pray event gets trigger. And I don't see ant downsides for that. I don't think that `monitor changes` is not more of a hustle than monitoring the static event. but is the correct way to go...

**Monitoring the list:**
Change the list to be an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and take a look at [NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ).
Monitor it by:

```
public class God {

    readonly ObservableCollection<Believer> Believers = new ObservableCollection<Believer>();

    public God() {
        Believers  = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        Believers.CollectionChanged += BelieversListChanged;
    }

    private void BelieversListChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args) {

        if ((e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove || e.Action ==     NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace) && e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var oldItem in e.OldItems)
            {
                var bel= (Believer)e.oldItem;               
                bel.Prayed -= Believer_Prayed; 
            }
        }

        if((e.Action==NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add ||               e.Action==NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace) && e.NewItems!=null)
            {
                foreach(var newItem in e.NewItems)
                {
                   foreach (var oldItem in e.OldItems)
                {
                    var bel= (Believer)e.newItem;               
                    bel.Prayed += Believer_Prayed; 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Believer_Prayed(Believer believer, string prayer) {
        //whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: ObservableCollection is how I would often do this (btw don't forget to handle the Reset-Action too), but note how much more code it is. And if I have 100.000 followers, it makes me feel silly to loop through all of them on startup and register the instance event. If I want to use the Believers collection for binding a have to use an ObservableCollection anyway, but it seems like a waste to have one just so I can register events.