# Can I make EventHandlers non static memberfunctions in C++/UWP?

Tags: c++, uwp, eventhandler

Maybe this question is a little bit stupid, but I'm stuck right now.

I'm currently working on a class with a TextBox and a TextBlock. When you type something in the TextBox the TextChangedEventHandler should update the TextBlock with the same Text. But because the EventHandler function is static i cant get the TextBlock, because it is non-static of course. Is there a way to do this properly, or can make EventHandlers non-static?

Here is my class:

```
class Test {
    TextBlock^ tbl;
    TextBox^ tb;
public:
    Test(StackPanel^ parent) {
        tbl = ref new TextBlock;
        tb = ref new TextBox;
        tb += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextChangedEventHandler(&tb_TextChanged);
        parent->Children->Append(tbl);
        parent->Children->Append(tb);
    }
    static void tb_TextChanged(Platform::Object ^sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextChangedEventArgs ^e) {
        tbl->Text = static_cast<TextBox^>(sender)->Text; //this doesnt work unfortunately! 
    }
};
```

`

Comment: When you make tb_TextChanged non-static then the TextChangedEventHandler delegate constructor requires a reference to the class object that contains the member function.  Pass `this` as the first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first of all thank you Hans Passant and Nico Zhu for your help. I couldn't use:

```
tb->TextChanged += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextChangedEventHandler(&tb_TextChanged);
```

because my class was a standard c++ class. I had to declare it as C++/CX first, like:

```
ref class Test sealed {
    ...
};
```

But with that defined i'm now able to pass "this" to the function.
<3

Answer (score 0):

Derive from [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045595/how-do-static-events-compare-to-non-static-events-in-c).

> Much of OOP can be thought of in terms of message passing.
>
> A method call is a message from the caller to the callee (carrying the parameters) and a message back with the return value.
>
> An event is a message from the source to the subscriber. There are thus potentially two instances involved, the one sending the message and the one receiving it.
>
> With a static event, there is no sending instance (just a type, which may or may not be a class). There still can be a recipient instance encoded as the target of the delegate.

You could use non-static subscriber for `TextChanged` like the following.

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    rootLayout = ref new StackPanel;
    
    tbl = ref new TextBlock;
    tb = ref new TextBox;
    rootLayout->Children->Append(tbl);
    rootLayout->Children->Append(tb);
    tb->TextChanged += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextChangedEventHandler(this, &App17::MainPage::OnTextChanged);
    Content = rootLayout;
}

void App17::MainPage::OnTextChanged(Platform::Object ^sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextChangedEventArgs ^e)
{
    tbl->Text = static_cast<TextBox^>(sender)->Text;
}
```